# How to replace Python keywords with Unicode values

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to compile Python with the keywords replaced with Unicode strings (equivalent keywords in a foreign language in my case). I decided to start with replacing the `import` statement as a test, so I modified my `Grammar/Grammar` file to look like this:

```
# For normal and annotated assignments, additional restrictions enforced by the interpreter
del_stmt: 'del' exprlist
pass_stmt: 'pass'
flow_stmt: break_stmt | continue_stmt | return_stmt | raise_stmt | yield_stmt
break_stmt: 'break'
continue_stmt: 'continue'
return_stmt: 'return' [testlist]
yield_stmt: yield_expr
raise_stmt: 'raise' [test ['from' test]]
import_stmt: import_name | import_from
import_name: '輸入' dotted_as_names # This is the only line I modified
# note below: the ('.' | '...') is necessary because '...' is tokenized as ELLIPSIS
import_from: ('from' (('.' | '...')* dotted_name | ('.' | '...')+)
              'import' ('*' | '(' import_as_names ')' | import_as_names))
import_as_name: NAME ['as' NAME]
dotted_as_name: dotted_name ['as' NAME]
import_as_names: import_as_name (',' import_as_name)* [',']
dotted_as_names: dotted_as_name (',' dotted_as_name)*
dotted_name: NAME ('.' NAME)*
global_stmt: 'global' NAME (',' NAME)*
nonlocal_stmt: 'nonlocal' NAME (',' NAME)*
assert_stmt: 'assert' test [',' test]
```

When I try to run `$ make -s -j2` I get this:

```
Translating labels ...
Can't translate STRING label '輸入'
```

If I try with non-Unicode values, it works fine, so I'm guessing this is an issue with Unicode compatibility. Is it just not supported or is there some way around it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible out of the box: the language reference states that [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) may be unicode, but the list of [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) is ascii.  If you know C, you could have a look at the parser code to see if it handles unicode - the error message you get is from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Parser/grammar.c#L267)